# Sublime Text 2 :: Python code completion

Tags: python, ide, sublimetext2, sublimetext

I'm trying to get Code suggestion (the drop-down box) to suggest properly.

Right now it does not. It only suggests, more or less, identifiers and modules
that are already in the file being edited (meaning in-file scope). If, for example, I try this:

import numpy <---  numpy is not suggested as I type it.

numpy.a <--- And here, nothing that begins with 'a' is suggested.

I've implemented a raft of things suggested at various sites, including the following, but
with no success in getting correct code-complete suggestions to appear,
or sometimes to appear at all:

```
- Installed SublimeRope
- "use_simple_completion": true  (in SublimeRope.sublime-settings)
- "auto_complete_triggers": [ {"selector": "source.python - string - comment - constant.numeroc", "characters": "."} ]  (in Pyhon.sublime-settings)
- etc.
```

Am I missing something (of course I am :)). Appreciate the suggestions.

Comment: That’s working as it should. Sublime Text doesn’t autocomplete arbitrary module names or their contents, as far as I know — even in Python.

Comment: As minitech said, you did nothing wrong, except that you think at SublimeText as some IDE. It is a text editor with nice interface. Even geany is better( but autocompletion sucks to). If you need to „explore” function from package/modules, try dreampie as shell( you may copy/paste code) or an real IDE (SPE, Ninja, Eric, Aptana, NetBeans, PyCharm ...)

Comment: Thank you minitech3 and cox. I do use "Komodo" and "Wing IDE" as full Python IDEs already (happy with Wing IDE especially); and from the tty I use the curses-based "bpython" (which is excellent, and has full auto complete). I was hoping SublimeText would be a nice cross between bython's lightness and Wing/Komodo's heavier experience. But I guess not as of this writing. Still, I like SublimeText and will use it. I appreciate the responses. :)

Comment: Not satisfied that SublimeText didn't do what I read it could (stated above), I tinkered some more. It seems I'm probably one setting off, because I discovered that there are two sets of suggestions that come up... (1) The first are in-scope suggestions based on contents already in the file, and (2) but if I back the cursor up one position and hit the dot (.) separator again (e.g. collections.Counter), *then* the complete list detailing the modules & functions I want to see appear. So there's probably a disambiguation setting that needs to be adjusted. I'll report back what that is when able.

Comment: I believe that this is properly a duplicate of "[Getting full JS autocompletion under Sublime Text](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13661462/1309332)", not the marked question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sublime's autocomplete is intended to match within the current file.

If you want to have code completion based on syntactic features of the language, you have many options, but I would suggest some combination of the following:

- Install the [CodeIntel package](https://github.com/Kronuz/SublimeCodeIntel) ([package control instructions here](https://tutsplus.com/lesson/package-control/))
- Use snippets

  - Install Python snippets through package control (I like sublime-unittest).
  - [Instructions for creating your own snippets](https://tutsplus.com/lesson/your-first-snippet/).

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you. It does. I actually had tried CodeIntel which is what got me closer to what I wanted, though it still struggles to auto-suggest correctly (and it's slows things down -- like any plugin naturally would -- some more that others). Your comment let me know I was going in the right direction (with the myriad of settings that there are). I'd upvote your response (because it's correct), but I only have a measly 6 points. :)

Comment: Just a heads up for others, the setup for CodeIntel is very difficult and the documentation is very poor.