# How to add code intellisense to external JS files in Sublime Text 3 using SublimeCodeIntel

Tags: javascript, sublimetext3, external, intellisense

If I have references to two external/custom JS script files inside my HTML, namely

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="xyz.com/xyz.js" type="text/javascript" />
```

or

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/xyz.js" type="text/javascript" />
```

I somehow cannot figure out how to use SublimeCodeIntel to work due to the lack of documentation. Could someone help me out here?

Comment: I think you should use some packages like [code intel](http://sublimecodeintel.github.io/SublimeCodeIntel/)

Comment: I have just rephrased my question to be a bit more clear. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways you can get the intelligent code awareness and auto-completion, as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13906219/3078890) and in addition to that of you want your own auto-completions to work you can check sublime official docs for [completion](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/completions.html) and [completion files](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/completions.html) and you can use [snippets](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/snippets.html) too.

for example of manually creation of auto-complete suggestion create file `myCompletion.sublime-completions`:

```
{
        "scope": "text.html - source - meta.tag, punctuation.definition.tag.begin",

        "completions":
        [
                { "trigger": "a", "contents": "<a href=\"$1\">$0</a>" },
                { "trigger": "abbr", "contents": "<abbr>$0</abbr>" },
                { "trigger": "acronym", "contents": "<acronym>$0</acronym>" },

                "ninja",
                "robot",
                "pizza"
        ]
}
```

Comment: Is there no way that I can set the plugin to "also look" into the referenced JS file in a way that it automatically starts picking the functions in my intellisense?

Comment: @PramodMohandas There is no chance for unknown scripts unless you add it yourself. but code intel (and ternjs) does it for most of libraries.

Comment: Yes, I'm OK to reference the script somewhere so that it starts picking it up. These JS files are third-party. Nothing that ST3 can do?

Comment: @PramodMohandas So that's the only way remains

Comment: How do I do that referencing? I still couldn't figure it out. Adding them to the project files list? Does SublimeCodeIntel have this capability?

Comment: You have to define your project. Search for tern-for-sublime or codeintl to find out more.

Comment: Looks like I'll have to drop ST3 and go with WebStorm. I was looking for a change in IDE for JS/CSS/HTML. I was trying to replicate this on ST3 - https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2014/07/how-webstorm-works-completion-for-javascript-libraries/